# Generate Z-Depth map from Stereo Image-Pair (just like nuke occula)

Tags: stereoscopy

How to calculate a Z-Depth Map and/or PointCloud from a 3D Stereoscopic image pair? This feature can be seen within nuke occula; which does a great job...

I've found tutorials using some CLI and PointCloud editors; but I'm more looking for a solution within blender compositor/3d

thanks

Comment: I don't believe computing depth from stereo-pair is a trivial computation. There is currently no feature in Blender I can think of that can achieve this.